# ASP.NET auth cookie: not sent back

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies

I've got a simple asp.net app and I'm using cookies to authenticate the user. Everything works out well when using Chrome or FF. However, when using IE, the auth cookie isn't being sent back. I can see that the authentication request sets the cookie (there's a set-cookie header) and does a redirect, but the next call (started by the redirect) does not send the cookie back to the server.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was in the name used for the domain. I was using a single name (name of the machine) and it seems like that is not a valid name for the cookie's domain name property.